Launchpad: How to set up a "fork" of an Ubuntu source package?
I'm currently trying to create a PPA that would automatically release linux-firmware packages from the latest Ubuntu for all Ubuntu releases.
To do that, I've created my project https://launchpad.net/linux-firmware-upstream . Now I'm stuck at the code import phase.
The git repo I'd like to "fork" (or just build without modifications in my project) is hosted on Launchpad at git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware .
However, I can't find a way to configure the code import.
I've tried both "Configure code" button in project options (https://launchpad.net/linux-firmware-upstream/+configure-code) and requesting a code import (https://code.launchpad.net/+code-imports/+new).
In both cases, when I enter various options into Git-to-Git import, I either get error "Invalid value" or "You cannot create same-VCS imports for branches or repositories that are hosted by Launchpad.".
The documentation is not helpful. The search button when configuring the import never found anything, so it's also not helpful.
Things I've tried to enter into the field "Link to a Git repository already on Launchpad":

git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware
~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware
lp:~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware
~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+git/noble
lp:~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+git/noble
~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+git/linux-firmware

How do I proceed so that I can set up a build recipe?
